# Possible to have a floating horizontal scrollbar on a datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a huge size of table and I want to have a scroll bar floating inside my table so I dont able to go in the bottom of the table in able to see the scroll bar.

Answers

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have a datatable from https://datatables.net/ now i just want a floating horizontal scrollbar when i scroll windows vertical scroll and when my datatable appears then horizontal scrollbar also appear in the bottom of the page i dont want to go to the end of the table i've mentioned a similar jquery plugin link can you please check it and tell me how to use this plugin in my datatable https://amphiluke.github.io/floating-scroll/

Comment: i am very thankful if you can do this for me i just want to integrate floating scrollbar with datatable